# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am facing an error to install the packages on aws ec2 instance with Ubuntu 18 using the following command -

`pip install -e .`

The error is -

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`

What did I check?

1. RAM using `free -h` command.
2. Disk utilization using `sudo ncdu -x` command.
3. Since `pip` tries to download to the default location given by `TMPDIR` variable, I also removed files from that location.
4. I removed contents from .cache directory.
5. I removed contents from /tmp directory.

Still I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 16):

The answer provided at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5816#issuecomment-425410189, states that

> pip downloads files to temporary directory, environment variable TMPDIR specifies that directory, also pip puts files into cache thus --cache-dir specification, --no-cache-dir should work too. --build specifies directory where wheel will be built, so its specification is also useful.

For my user, I made a custom directory named `codebase/pip_cache/` in my home directory.

First I tried `--no-cache-dir` using the following command -

`TMPDIR=/home/deepakahire/codebase/pip_cache/ pip install -e . --no-cache-dir`. This didn't work.

Finally, I specified the `--cache-dir` as well, and used the following command to install the package -

`TMPDIR=/home/deepakahire/codebase/pip_cache/ pip install --cache-dir=/home/deepakahire/codebase/pip_cache/ -e .` This worked for me.

Caveat-
Blindly deleting everything from `/tmp` directory would delete your tmux sessions, but will still keep the services/instances alive on the same ports, which were switched on in any tmux session previously.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is more in alignment with newer versions of PIP, as it complained `--build` wasn't recognized. But I also had to create a swap partition for on my EC2 because it kept running out of memory just from downloading the file.

Comment: After installing like this, my venv doesnt recognize the installed packages, any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: I was able to fix this issue on a t2.micro AWS Linux machine by running a similar command:
`python3.11 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --cache-dir=/home/ec2-user/pip_cache/ `